# How to sync my contacts in my iPhone 6 to a Mercedes C300 bluetooth handsfree?

Tags: iphone, contacts, bluetooth

I need to transfer my iPhone 6 contacts so I can use them on my Mercedes Benz C300 handsfree device without having to manually dial a phone number on my iPhone while driving. I used to have a BlackBerry and the syncing worked perfectly. Now I just can't find a way to transfer the contacts to the car.

Comment: did you try this instructions ? http://www.mbusa.com/mercedes/owners/videos/detail/videoId-561ca058f002d310VgnVCM2000007d184335RCRD  the section about access address book ?